# JSON.stringify serialising date incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json

If I have the following date in milliseconds:

*Tue Apr 03 1984 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)*

When I run:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Date(449794800000)))
```

It's output is:

> "1984-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"

However the output should be:

> "1984-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Because Unix timestamp `449794800` is `1984-04-02T23:00:00.000Z`. Why do you think it's one month earlier?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`actually calls the `.toJSON` method of the date object and the method returns the string `"1984-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"`. It doesn't affect how `.toJSON` method of the date object  works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the ISO date format and is a standard way of sending dates. It is unambiguous and easy to parse, but not designed for maximum human readability. `JSON.stringify()` has been written to treat dates specially like this, because a date is not a JSON value. You can do `JSON.stringify(date.toString())` instead if you want it to be more human readable. The reason for the date change is that it switches timezones from yours (GMT+1) to GMT, so it goes back an hour and ends up on the previous day.

If you want to create a date object storing the start of a day at GMT, you can do the following:

```
const dateHere = new Date(2017, 7, 4)
//60000 ms per minute
const utcMillis = dateHere.getTime() - dateHere.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
const utcDate = new Date(utcMillis)
console.log(utcDate.toISOString()) //"2017-08-04T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 449794800000 in dateTime in javascript is "1984-04-02T23:00:00.000Z"

Try it yourself, run

```
console.log(new Date(449794800000)).
```

In fact, comparing it to unix time, (using [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) and dividing your number by 1000 to transform from milliseconds to seconds), the date is correct. It should be "1984-04-02T23:00:00.000Z" and not "1984-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"